# Launch Apple Watch messages app from within another watch app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to launch the messages app on the Apple Watch from my own WatchKit app. I've seen this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016154/launch-watch-kit-app-from-within-another-watch-kit-app), but it only tells me to forward the app launch to the iPhone.

In the delegate method of the iPhone app, I can now perform a URL action. What's the URL I have to use in order to launch the messages app on the **watch**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in watchOS 1.

In watchOS 2, you'll be able to call `openSystemURL` on the `WKExtension` object and use the `sms` scheme. Documentation is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/ManagingYourData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH12-SW11).